# WPF app Freeze after minimizing the window for some time

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I developed a WPF app which is working in normal scenario. However, in the following scenario the app is frozen.

Scenario:
1. Start the app
2. Minimize the window
3. Leave it for 20 -30 min
4. Maximise the window and seen app is frozen.

If I minimise and maximise the window app starts working normal again.

I use BusyIndicator from ExtendedToolKit during start up while fetching information from database using background worker.

Any idea would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you using cached composition?  e.g., `BitmapCache`

Comment: No I am not using. The issue is very sporadic as well..I suspect it's something to do with connecting database via WCF service..